# Bootstrap 5 Navbar dropdown won't direct to another page an is experiencing a styling glitch

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

-1

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a website and I also used Bootstrap 5 to create the navbar. I added my own css so that the services dropdown will open on hover. However when someone clicks on the services dropdown I want them to be directed to the services page, but when I click on the services dropdown nothing happens. Every other dropdown on the navbar works and directs the user to the desired page. I was told earlier that data-bs-toggle="dropdown" was blocking it from redirecting to the desired page, so I removed it. I noticed that if I take off data-bs-toggle="dropdown", on the mobile site the dropdown doesn't open and close and only directs the user to the services page, but on desktop site it works fine. Would you have any ideas to get around this? I also noticed that if I keep `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` along with the CSS code that allows the dropdown to open on hover that if I click on the dropdown on the desktop version of the site that it opens but if you move your cursor off the items of the dropdown, two white bars appear on the dropdown. One on top of the dropdown and one on the bottom of the dropdown. this is what it looks like [image]

### Test.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/index.html">
          <img src="./assets/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link text-white">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white">Contact</a></li>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION START -->
    
        <button 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        data-bs-toggle="modal" 
        data-bs-target="#loginmodal"
      >
        Login/Signup
      </button>
      <div id="loginmodal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <button 
                type="button" 
                class="btn-close btn-close-white" 
                data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
              >
              </button>
              <div class="myform bg-dark">
                <h1 class="text-center" id="modal-styling">Login Form</h1>
                <form action="#">
                  <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="passeord" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mt-3">LOGIN</button>
                  <p id="modal-styling">Don't have an account? <a href="#" id="modal-styling">Signup</a> </p>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION CLOSE -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

    
  </body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }
}



@media (min-width: 576px) {
    footer li:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    footer i:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
}

#navmenu li{
    background:hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
    transition: all;
}

#navmenu li:hover {
    background: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#sub-header {
    color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}
```

### After Adding JS

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <button
    type="button"
    class="navbar-toggler"
    data-bs-toggle="collapse"
    data-bs-target="#navmenu"
  >
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
  </button>
  <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

  <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link text-white">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false">
    Services
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
    <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
    <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
    
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white">Contact</a></li>

  <script>
    // Get the Services dropdown link element
    const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
  
    // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
    servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
      window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
    });
  
    // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
      // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
      servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
        this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
      });
  
      // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
      servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
        this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

    
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
        margin-top: 0;
        width: 175px;

        .btn {
            color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        }

        .dropdown-item:hover {
            background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
        }
    }
}



@media (min-width: 576px) {
    footer li:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    footer i:hover {
        color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
        transition: 0.2s;
    }
}

#navmenu li{
    background:hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
    transition: all;
}

#navmenu li:hover {
    background: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#sub-header {
    color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/index.html">
          <img src="./assets/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link text-white">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white">Contact</a></li>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION START -->
    
        <button 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        data-bs-toggle="modal" 
        data-bs-target="#loginmodal"
      >
        Login/Signup
      </button>
      <div id="loginmodal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <button 
                type="button" 
                class="btn-close btn-close-white" 
                data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
              >
              </button>
              <div class="myform bg-dark">
                <h1 class="text-center" id="modal-styling">Login Form</h1>
                <form action="#">
                  <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="passeord" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mt-3">LOGIN</button>
                  <p id="modal-styling">Don't have an account? <a href="#" id="modal-styling">Signup</a> </p>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION CLOSE -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem might be caused by the data-bs-toggle="dropdown" attribute in the "Services" link. When you remove this attribute, the link starts working correctly on desktop but loses the dropdown functionality.

To fix this, you can use **JavaScript** to handle the dropdown behavior on desktop while allowing the link to work on mobile.

Comment: can you please help me with the JavaScript I don't know JavaScript

Comment: Sure here how to solve the problem!

Comment: thank you for your help but it didn't work I don't know if ots because I did something wrong. I edited my question to include what my code looks like

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the **data-bs-toggle="dropdown"** attribute from the "Services" dropdown anchor () element to allow redirection to the services page.

And you have to add an event listener to the "Services" dropdown anchor element to handle the click event and redirect the user to the services page when clicked.

```html
<!-- ... (your other code) ... -->

<li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="/services.html" role="button" aria-expanded="false" id="servicesDropdown">
    Services
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- your dropdown menu items -->
  </ul>
</li>

<!-- ... (your other code) ... -->

<script>
  // Get the Services dropdown link element
  const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');

  // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
  servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
    window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
  });

  // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
  if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
    // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
    servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
      this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
    });

    // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
    servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
    });
  }
</script>
```

With these changes, the "Services" dropdown will now redirect to the services page when clicked, and the hover effect will be applied on desktop devices, allowing the dropdown menu to open and close as expected.

Comment: thank you for your help but it didn't work I don't know if ots because I did something wrong. I edited my question to include what my code looks like